# Destruct object of array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Hi Guys I have an array of objects, which I want to destruct. **The following is an excerpt of the array.**

```
[
  {
    "Area": "Werk Produktivität [%] - Target",
    "Jan": 86.21397507374327,
    "Feb": 86.0570021973368,
    "Mrz": 88.70898346258058,
    "Apr": 85.29801908413164,
    "May": 85.07431241640211
  },
  {
    "Area": "Werk Produktivität [%] - Actual",
    "Jan": 84.17054711398421,
    "Feb": 83.80826026601528,
    "Mrz": 84.11553769971036,
    "Apr": 83.76460916731,
    "May": 82.69773876702813
  }
]
```

What I now try to achieve is splitting the array into the following :

```
[
  {
    "Area": "Werk Produktivität [%] - Target",
    "Jan": 86.21397507374327,

  },
  {
    "Area": "Werk Produktivität [%] - Target",
    "Feb": 86.0570021973368,
   
  },
  {
    "Area": "Werk Produktivität [%] - Target",
    "Mrz": 88.70898346258058,

  },
  {
    "Area": "Werk Produktivität [%] - Target",
    "Apr": 85.29801908413164,

  },
  {
    "Area": "Werk Produktivität [%] - Target",
    "May": 85.07431241640211,
  },
  {
    "Area": "Werk Produktivität [%] - Actual",
    "Jan": 84.17054711398421,

  },
  {
    "Area": "Werk Produktivität [%] - Actual",
    "Feb": 83.80826026601528,
  },
  {
    "Area": "Werk Produktivität [%] - Actual",
    "Mrz": 84.11553769971036,

  },
    {
    "Area": "Werk Produktivität [%] - Actual",
    "Apr": 83.76460916731,
  },
   {
    "Area": "Werk Produktivität [%] - Actual",
    "May": 82.69773876702813
  }
```

I was thinking of using the `...rest` parameter the following way but I only get the last 5 items of the array. Please note that obj is above excerpt of the object of array.

```
const fn = ({ Area, ...rest }) =>
  Object.values(rest)
    .map(Month => ({
      Area,
      Month
    }))
       


})
const result = fn(obj)
```

Comment: What do you mean *"but I only get the last 5 items of the array"* ? You might get nested arrays as output. Something like: `const output = inputArray.flatMap(fn)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `obj` in `result = fn(obj)` does here. I think you are calling `map` on the array and getting the first item in the resulting 2D array. You just need to call `flatMap` on the array with `fn` as the callback.

```
const output = inputArray.flatMap(fn)
```

or

```
const output = inputArray.map(fn).flat()
```

Also the `fn` needs to be tweaked a bit. You need to get the entires of the `rest` object since you need the key of the object as well

```
Object.entries(rest)
      .map(([key, value]) => ({ Area, [key]: value }))
```

```js
const input = [
  {
    "Area": "Werk Produktivität [%] - Target",
    "Jan": 86.21397507374327,
    "Feb": 86.0570021973368,
    "Mrz": 88.70898346258058,
    "Apr": 85.29801908413164,
    "May": 85.07431241640211
  },
  {
    "Area": "Werk Produktivität [%] - Actual",
    "Jan": 84.17054711398421,
    "Feb": 83.80826026601528,
    "Mrz": 84.11553769971036,
    "Apr": 83.76460916731,
    "May": 82.69773876702813
  }
]

const fn = ({ Area, ...rest }) =>
  Object.entries(rest)
    .map(([key,value]) => ({
      Area,
      [key]: value
    }))

const output = input.flatMap(fn)

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `reduce` and `Object.entries` for getting result same as :

```js
const data = [
  {
    "Area": "Werk Produktivität [%] - Target",
    "Jan": 86.21397507374327,
    "Feb": 86.0570021973368,
    "Mrz": 88.70898346258058,
    "Apr": 85.29801908413164,
    "May": 85.07431241640211
  },
  {
    "Area": "Werk Produktivität [%] - Actual",
    "Jan": 84.17054711398421,
    "Feb": 83.80826026601528,
    "Mrz": 84.11553769971036,
    "Apr": 83.76460916731,
    "May": 82.69773876702813
  }
]
const result  = data.reduce((res, {Area, ...rest}) => {
  Object.entries(rest).forEach(([key, value]) => res.push({Area, [key]: value}))
  return res
}, [])
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `Array.prototype.reduce` and inside of it the function `Array.prototype.map` to build the desired object.

```js
const arr = [  {    "Area": "Werk Produktivität [%] - Target",    "Jan": 86.21397507374327,    "Feb": 86.0570021973368,    "Mrz": 88.70898346258058,    "Apr": 85.29801908413164,    "May": 85.07431241640211  },  {    "Area": "Werk Produktivität [%] - Actual",    "Jan": 84.17054711398421,    "Feb": 83.80826026601528,    "Mrz": 84.11553769971036,    "Apr": 83.76460916731,    "May": 82.69773876702813  }];
const result = arr.reduce((a, {Area, ...months}) => {
  return [...a, ...Object.entries(months).map(([month, value]) => ({Area, [month]: value}))];
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const ary = [
  {
    "Area": "Werk Produktivität [%] - Target",
    "Jan": 86.21397507374327,
    "Feb": 86.0570021973368,
    "Mrz": 88.70898346258058,
    "Apr": 85.29801908413164,
    "May": 85.07431241640211
  },
  {
    "Area": "Werk Produktivität [%] - Actual",
    "Jan": 84.17054711398421,
    "Feb": 83.80826026601528,
    "Mrz": 84.11553769971036,
    "Apr": 83.76460916731,
    "May": 82.69773876702813
  }
];

const newAry = [];

for(item of ary){
  const {
    Area,
    ...months
  }=item;
  for([k,v] of Object.entries(months)){
    newAry.push({Area,[k]:v});
    
  }
}
console.log(newAry);
```

Hope this helps you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve that by using [`Destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Demo **:**

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "Area": "Werk Produktivität [%] - Target",
    "Jan": 86.21397507374327,
    "Feb": 86.0570021973368,
    "Mrz": 88.70898346258058,
    "Apr": 85.29801908413164,
    "May": 85.07431241640211
  },
  {
    "Area": "Werk Produktivität [%] - Actual",
    "Jan": 84.17054711398421,
    "Feb": 83.80826026601528,
    "Mrz": 84.11553769971036,
    "Apr": 83.76460916731,
    "May": 82.69773876702813
  }
];

const res = [];

arr.forEach(obj => {
    const {Area, ...remaining} = obj;
  Object.keys(remaining).forEach(month => {
    res.push({ Area, [month]: remaining[month] })
  })
})

console.log(res);
```